# If $\mathcal{F}$ globally generated, then counit map $f^*f_* \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F} $ surjective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f: X \to S$ be a morphism, and $\mathcal{F}$
be quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module *generated by global sections* (eg if
$X$ projective, then this holds for the twisted sheaf $\mathcal{F}(n)$ for large enough $n$) and
we additionally require that *the pushforward sheaf $f_* \mathcal{F}$ is
quasi-coherent* too (eg. this should hold if $X$ Noetherian and $f$ proper)

Question: Why this would imply that then the counit map

$$   c:f^*f_* \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}   $$

is surjective?

Source: [these notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ebejleri/teaching/math259xfa19/math259x_fullnotes.pdf) (page 25)
Some remarks: the question is local, since surjectivity is equivalent to
surjectivity stalkwise, therefore we way assume $S$ be affine.
Moreover in the linked source is assumed that $f_* \mathcal{F}$ is even (locally) free,
not sure if it is really neccessary, or already coherence of $f_* \mathcal{F}$ suffice.

And even if we assume that  $f_* \mathcal{F} \cong \mathcal{O}_S^d$ is free, why then the counit map $c: f^*\mathcal{O}_S^d = \mathcal{O}_X^d \to \mathcal{F}$ should map the canonical generators $(0,...,1,...0) := \widehat{e_i} \in \mathcal{O}_S(S)^d$ exactly to *global generators* of $\mathcal{F}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No assumptions on $f_* f^* \mathcal F$ are necessary. The point is just that the global sections of $f_* \mathcal F$ are the global sections of $\mathcal F$ and thus generate $\mathcal F$.

In more detail, let $s$ be a section of $\mathcal F$ on an open set $U$. Then by the assumption that $\mathcal F$ is generated by global sections, we have $s = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \gamma_i$ with $a_i \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal O_U)$ and $\gamma_i \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$. By definition $\Gamma(S, f_* \mathcal F)= \Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$ so $\gamma_1,\dots, \gamma_n$ correspond to global sections of $f_* \mathcal F$. By the definition of pullback, $\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n$ therefore also give sections of $f^* f_* \mathcal F$, which the counit map sends to the original $\gamma_1,\dots, \gamma_n$. Multiplying these by $a_i$ and summing gives an element of $\Gamma(U, f^* f_* \mathcal F)$ that projects to $s$, showing that $c$ is surjective (even on the level of presheaves).

Answer (score 3):

The morphism $f^*f_*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}$ is induced by the counit of adjunction $f^*f_* \to \mathrm{id}$. Therefore, there is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^0(\mathcal{F}) \otimes f^*f_*\mathcal{O}_X @>>> 
H^0(\mathcal{F}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X
\\
@VVV @VVV
\\
f^*f_*\mathcal{F} @>>> \mathcal{F}.
\end{CD}
Therefore, the surjectivity for $\mathcal{F}$ reduces to the surjectivity for $\mathcal{O}_X$, which is obvious.